# How do I grep for multiple patterns on multiple lines?

Tags: command-line, grep, text-processing

To be precise

```
Some text
begin
Some text goes here.
end
Some more text
```

and I want to extract entire block that starts from "begin" till "end".

with awk we can do like `awk '/begin/,/end/' text`.

How to do with grep?

Comment: [Same question on Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/168813/how-do-i-grep-for-multiple-patterns-on-multiple-lines). [Don't do that](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**Updated 18-Nov-2016** (since grep behavior is changed: grep with -P parameter now doesn't support `^` and `$` anchors [on Ubuntu 16.04 with kernel v:4.4.0-21-generic])([wrong (non-)fix](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/324263/72456))

```
$ grep -Pzo "begin(.|\n)*\nend" file
begin
Some text goes here.  
end
```

note: for other commands just replace the '^' & '$' anchors with new-line anchor `'\n'`
______________________________

With grep command:

```bsh
grep -Pzo "^begin\$(.|\n)*^end$" file
```

If you want don't include the patterns "begin" and "end" in result, use grep with Lookbehind and Lookahead support.

```bsh
grep -Pzo "(?<=^begin$\n)(.|\n)*(?=\n^end$)" file
```

Also you can use `\K` notify instead of Lookbehind assertion.

```bsh
grep -Pzo "^begin$\n\K(.|\n)*(?=\n^end$)" file
```

`\K` option ignore everything before pattern matching and ignore pattern itself.
`\n` used for avoid printing empty lines from output.

Or as @AvinashRaj suggests there are simple easy grep as following:

```bsh
grep -Pzo "(?s)^begin$.*?^end$" file

grep -Pzo "^begin\$[\s\S]*?^end$" file
```

`(?s)` tells grep to allow the dot to match newline characters.
`[\s\S]` matches any character that is either whitespace or non-whitespace.

And their output without including "begin" and "end" is as following:

```bsh
grep -Pzo "^begin$\n\K[\s\S]*?(?=\n^end$)" file # or grep -Pzo "(?<=^begin$\n)[\s\S]*?(?=\n^end$)"

grep -Pzo "(?s)(?<=^begin$\n).*?(?=\n^end$)" file
```

[see the full test of all commands here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/9096940/) (<sub>out of dated as grep behavior with -P parameter is changed</sub>)

#### Note:

`^` point the beginning of a line and `$` point the end of a line. these added to the around of "begin" and "end" to matching them if they are alone in a line.
In two commands I escaped `$` because it also using for "Command Substitution"(`$(command)`) that allows the output of a command to replace the command name.

#### From man grep:

```bsh
-o, --only-matching
      Print only the matched (non-empty) parts of a matching line,
      with each such part on a separate output line.

-P, --perl-regexp
      Interpret PATTERN as a Perl compatible regular expression (PCRE)

-z, --null-data
      Treat the input as a set of lines, each terminated by a zero byte (the ASCII 
      NUL character) instead of a newline. Like the -Z or --null option, this option 
      can be used with commands like sort -z to process arbitrary file names.
```

Comment: change your grep like `grep -Pzo "(?<=begin\n)(.|\n)*(?=\nend)" file` to not to print `\n` character which exists on the line begin.

Comment: Use DOTALL modifier to make dot to match even newline chars also `grep -Pzo "(?s)begin.*?end" file`

Comment: Or Simply, `grep -Pzo "begin[\s\S]*?end" file`

Comment: @AvinashRaj thank you I added to avoiding `\n` but you can post your another solution as your own answer ;)

Comment: Why? add it to yours. I have more reps :-)

Comment: You might want to use `grep -Pzo "begin(.|\n)*\nend" file` instead to make sure that `end` only matches at the beginning of a line and not in things like `bend`.

Comment: @terdon Can I use `^end` instead? or even better `^end$`?

Comment: Huh, yes you can . I had thought that the `^` would only match the beginning of the file when using `-z` but apparently not.

Comment: @terdon yes that is but in upper case of `-Z` I think.

Comment: The man page says: "-z: Treat  the  input  as  a set of lines, each terminated by a zero byte (the ASCII NUL character) instead of a newline." so I would expect the `^` and `$` to match just before and just after a `\0` instead. Apparently, they're hard coded to match `\n`.

Comment: @KasiyA it would be `grep -Pzo "(?s)(?<=^|\n)begin.*?\nend" file`

Comment: The siólution doesn't work. It produces an error: `grep: ein nicht geschütztes ^ oder $ wird mit -Pz nicht unterstützt` The translation of the error is something like: `grep: a not protected ^ or $ is not supported with -Pz`

Comment: I guess `grep`'s behavior has changed. I just tested and musbach is right, the `^` and `$` don't work with `-Pz`. It should work as expected if your replace `^` and `$` with `\n` though.

Comment: @terdon http://paste.ubuntu.com/9096940/

Comment: Yes, I know, that's in your answer. I'm sure it worked when you posted this, but try it again today. The behavior of `grep` seems to have changed.

Comment: @terdon you are right. This works: `grep -Pzo "begin\n(.|\n)*\nend\n" file`. If I put before `begin` a `\n` (`grep -Pzo "\nbegin\n(.|\n)*\nend\n" file`) I get blank line and than the correct output. I guess that `\n` produces a linefeed but it looks strange to me. @KasiyA I am on Ubuntu 16.04. On what OS are you?

Comment: @musbach yes, `\n` is the newline character. You get an extra newline because with `\nbegin` you are including the newline character at the end of the previous line, so that's printed as a blank line.

Comment: at that time I was on 14.04, but right now I'm far away from my Ubuntu 16.04 to test it, once I come with 16.04 will double check, but for sure grep behavior is changed as *Mr. terdon* confirmed, @musbach

Comment: Yes, the answer should be corrected or flaged as wrong.

Comment: I have asked this grep _wrong behavior_ [grep command doesn't support start '^' and '$' end of line anchors when it's with -Pz](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/324263) @terdon

Comment: I added also that it works on 14.04 and it doesn't work not on 10.4 and it doesn't work on 16.04 (see blow). Why it just works on 14.04 is very strange.

Comment: @musbach there's no way (and no reason) to flag an answer as wrong. You've left a comment explaining it, that's all that's needed. The answer was correct when posted, after all.

Answer (score 3):

In case your `grep` doesn't support perl syntax (`-P`), you can try joining the lines, matching the pattern, then expanding the lines again as below:

```
$ tr '\n' , < foo.txt | grep -o "begin.*end" | tr , '\n'
begin
Some text goes here.
end
```