# filter lines containing a keyword and an ID if the ID appears on another line again

Tags: command-line, grep, text-processing, regex

This question is a variation of [How do I grep for multiple patterns on multiple lines?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/551338/how-do-i-grep-for-multiple-patterns-on-multiple-lines)

This is the sample text where lines containing "reqId: regexpat" or "reqCompleted: regexpat" should be matched in pairs where 'regexpat' is unique, in fact it may be a UUID.

```
2016-09-27 GET /some/uri - reqId: 000-pat1-bgr, more text 
2016-09-27 GET /some/uri - reqId: 0.215487, your favourite song
2016-09-27 irrelevant message
2016-09-27 ignored record
2016-09-27 reqCompleted: 999-xxx-vvv, ignore this
2016-09-27 reqCompleted: 0.215487, more characters
2016-09-27 reqCompleted: 000-pat1-bgr, more characters
2016-09-27 another lost message
```

The expected result should be

```
2016-09-27 GET /some/uri - reqId: 000-pat1-bgr, more text 
2016-09-27 GET /some/uri - reqId: 0.215487, your favourite song
2016-09-27 reqCompleted: 0.215487, more characters
2016-09-27 reqCompleted: 000-pat1-bgr, more characters
```

000-pat1-bgr and 0.215487 are unique identifiers. I have tried grep with perl-regex support

```
grep --null-data --only-matching --perl-regex '(?s)^\N+ RequestId:\1, \N+$\n(?:.*)^\N+ reqCompleted: ([a-z0-9\.-]+), .\N+$\n'
```

But this is what I get

```
2016-09-27 GET /some/uri - reqId: 000-pat1-bgr, more text 
2016-09-27 GET /some/uri - reqId: 0.215487, your favourite song
2016-09-27 irrelevant message
2016-09-27 ignored record
2016-09-27 reqCompleted: 999-xxx-vvv, ignore this
2016-09-27 reqCompleted: 0.215487, more characters
2016-09-27 reqCompleted: 000-pat1-bgr, more characters
```

Is it possible to achieve that with a one liner grep command?

Comment: So you only want the `reqId` and `reqCompleted` lines and nothing in between? Then just grep for those two words.

Comment: yes, but pattern after that should be unique, in fact it can be a UUID.

Comment: I don't understand. So you want to match only the first line where a pattern occurs?

Comment: I want to correlate lines according to a unique ID, that's why I tried to use back or forward references.

Comment: Why this line"2016-09-27 reqCompleted: 999-xxx-vvv, ignore this" should ignore while it has uniq number?

Comment: because there is not record containing "reqId:  999-xxx-vvv" in the sample. reqId signals the start of the request and reqCompleted the end of it. Only lines matching unique IDs in pairs should be returned.

Comment: Actually this line is uniq only, but what you want to point it, it has to be have a pair, I got your point, I hope , please confirm your file format is what you titled in your Q

Comment: yes, the sample is correct. there are 2 important patterns: 'reqId: uniquestring,' and 'reqCompleted: uniquestring,' . The sample may or may not contain the 2 patterns in pairs. Real sample will be taken for example from a server log filtering by dates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

another awk way to keep the line order since of using grep

```bsh
awk -F"[:,]" '/reqCompleted/ || /reqId/{
  dupsIDs[$(NF-1)]++
}END{
   for (x in dupsIDs)
     if (dupsIDs[x]==2) print x
}' infile |grep -f - infile

2016-09-27 GET /some/uri - reqId: 000-pat1-bgr, more text
2016-09-27 GET /some/uri - reqId: 0.215487, your favourite song
2016-09-27 reqCompleted: 0.215487, more characters
2016-09-27 reqCompleted: 000-pat1-bgr, more characters
```

Comment: Nice trick, create patterns with awk and feed grep with them from stdout. :) thx a lot for your time.

Comment: correct, I wrote stdout by mistake :-p

Comment: vote it up ad forgot to accept :-P. done

Answer (score 0):

Using `awk`, found solution:

```bsh
awk 'BEGIN{FS=":|,";i=0;}
/reqCompleted/ || /reqId/{
    arr[$i]=$2; 
    lines[$i]=$0; 
    i++;
}END{
    for(key in arr){
         if(arr[key] in arr){
         }else{
             print lines[key]
         };
    }
}' input.txt
```

This gives expected output as:

```
2016-09-27 reqCompleted: 000-pat1-bgr, more characters
2016-09-27 GET /some/uri - reqId: 0.215487, your favourite song
2016-09-27 reqCompleted: 0.215487, more characters
2016-09-27 GET /some/uri - reqId: 000-pat1-bgr, more text
```

Comment: Thanks snoop, looks good but for some reason lines are out of order. Samples will be mostly from an app log file in time order. You can add time to date if you want to help keep the order.

Comment: it gets closer by using NR instead of $i but shows the '999-xxx-vvv' record too :p