# Multi-line group capturing between braces

Tags: command-line, grep, regex

I have something like this in a file `testtt`:

```
{It captures this! }
// question: 2572410  name: Question 2

::Question 2::[html] Is it going to be -40 tomorrow?

{
It can't
capture this!!! why?
}
```

when I do:

```
grep -o '{\([^}]*\)}' testttt
```

It can't capture the multi-line braces. Any help to modify it in way that it could capture both would be apppreciated!

PS. I have also tested the given solution from: [How do I grep for multiple patterns on multiple lines?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/551338/how-do-i-grep-for-multiple-patterns-on-multiple-lines)
and it gives the following error:

```
grep: unescaped ^ or $ not supported with -Pz
```

You can find the text file of the output and file contents [here](https://paste.ubuntu.com/23417866/)

Comment: by the way when I test the same thing in the http://regexr.com/ it works fine! (you need to remove escapes and quotation there to work)

Comment: @KasiyA So I'm trying the first given command in the given solution from: http://askubuntu.com/questions/551338/how-do-i-grep-for-multiple-patterns-on-multiple-lines       and I get the following error:  grep: unescaped ^ or $ not supported with -Pz

Comment: Could you please post text files, dialogue messages, and program output listings as text, not as images? To achieve the latter two you can either 1) select, copy & paste the dialogue text or terminal content or 2) [save the program output to a file](//askubuntu.com/q/420981/175814) and use that. Longer listings (>100 lines) should be uploaded to a [pastie service](https://paste.ubuntu.com/) and linked to in the question. Thanks.

Comment: Your original question was about a multiline match between braces, if you have another question about matching line beginnings / endings when in `-z` (null terminated) mode you should ask that separately IMHO (the answer will probably be to use explicit `\n` characters, something like `grep -Pzo "begin\n(.|\n)*\nend"` or `grep -Pzo "(?s)begin\n.*\nend"`)

Comment: @steeldriver The reason that I edited my question was it go marked duplicated by different users so I tried the given solution in the refered post to test that is working for me or not!, removing caret and $ sign will make it work in this case but still this doesn't change the fact that the given solution maybe needs to be edited! Thanks for your attention!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, `grep` reads and processes single lines.

In newer versions of `grep`, you can use the `-z` option to tell it to consider its input to be null separated instead of newline separated; since your input doesn't have null terminations, that's essentially equivalent to perl's 'slurp' mode. So you could do

```
$ grep -zPo '{[^}]*}' testttt
{It captures this! }
{
It can't
capture this!!! why?
}
```

or, more perlishly, using a `.*?` non-greedy match with `(?s)` to include newlines in `.`

```
$ grep -zPo '(?s){.*?}' testttt
{It captures this! }
{
It can't
capture this!!! why?
}
```

Alternatively, if `pcregrep` is available,

```
$ pcregrep -Mo '(?s){.*?}' testttt
{It captures this! }
{
It can't
capture this!!! why?
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In order to trigger multi-line search with `grep` you have to add few option more, so try:

```
 grep -Pzo '(?s){.*?}' testttt
```

Solution with nice explanation can be found (and is stolen:) ) from [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3717772/3526890).

If you have `pcregrep` you may find it more useful in general case as it supports PERL 5 regex.