# grep – show lines until certain pattern

Tags: command-line, grep

I am on Ubuntu 16.04 and I want to search files for let’s say “if” and I want to the output until “endif”. The file could look like this

```
if …
  SOME CODE
endif
```

I can do this with `grep -A9 if my_file | grep -B9 endif`. 
This doesn’t works if the “if” clause is larger than 9 and if several “if” clauses are in the same file and if the first grep command contains several “if” clauses. The option `-m1` in the second grep doesn’t help. Nested “if” clauses can be ignored. Has somebody an idea, maybe not with grep?

Difference to [How do I grep for multiple patterns on multiple lines?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/551338/how-do-i-grep-for-multiple-patterns-on-multiple-lines)

1. The question asks for a solution with `grep` which is answered already in the question: `grep -A9 if my_file | grep -B9 endif`. The solution doesn’t work in my case but would work in the case of the other question.
2. The proposed grep solutions of the other question don’t work (with Ubuntu?): `grep: ein nicht geschütztes ^ oder $ wird mit -Pz nicht unterstützt.` which is something like `grep: a not protected ^ or $ is not supported with -Pz`. I use the following:

   ```
   root:/tmp# cat file
   Some text
   begin
   Some text goes here.  
   end
   Some more text 
   root:/tmp# grep -Pzo "^begin\$(.|\n)*^end$" file
   grep: ein nicht geschütztes ^ oder $ wird mit -Pz nicht unterstützt
   ```
3. The proposed solutions search only for pattern which start at the beginning of the line if I interpret the proposed solution correctly. Even if I remove `^` the command doesn't work.

Comment: About 2: Show us what pattern you used with `grep -Pz`. 3. What is a "pure Linux solution"? 4. `grep` can look anywhere in the line.

Comment: 2) You can edit your post, as you very well know. 3) LOL, Perl is not a secondary package by a long shot. It's as likely to be present on any Linux system as grep or sed. 4) So you know what `^` does.

Comment: 2) The trick was to put 8 (!) blanks in front because it is inside of a numbering. 3) I refer to the `pcregrep` and so on of the answer of steeldriver. But it is a matter of tasked, as I said. Anyway I have taken it out. 3) Yes, but even without `^` it doesn’t work.

Comment: The title doesn't fit the question: it should be `Show lines between two patterns`. Whoever wants lines from the first line on, doesn't get his answer here

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can use `sed` for that:

```
sed -n '/if/,/endif/p' myfile
```

- `-n` don't print anything until we ask for it
- `/if/` find the first line with this
- `,` keep going until...
- `/endif/` this is the last line we want
- `p` print the matched lines

Comment: Indeed, `sed` or (better!) `awk` are precisely the tools for this, as standard programs that have built-in begin/end pattern matching.

Comment: @Zanna, What should be in place of "," if I want to keep going up in the text, not down?

Comment: @JosefKlimuk I am not aware of a way. Can only suggest you put the top pattern or first line number you want to match first without further info. You could ask a question with details of your use case :)

Comment: @Zanna, "Can only suggest you put the top pattern or first line number you want to match first without further info". Simple and good. Thanks

Answer (score 8):

Traditional `grep` is line-oriented. To do multiline matches, you either need to fool it into slurping the whole file by telling it that your input is null terminated e.g.

```
grep -zPo '(?s)\nif.*\nendif' file
```

or use a more flexible tool such as `pcregrep`

```
pcregrep -M '(?s)\nif.*?\nendif' file
```

or perl itself

```
perl -00 -ne 'print if m/^if.*?endif/s' file
```

Alternatively, for matching *structured* input in a grep-like way, there's `sgrep`

```
sgrep '"if" .. ("endif") containing "SOME CODE"' file
```

Comment: AFAIK, trying to fool `grep` _et al._ by specifying a nonexistent (or even just very rare) terminator is inherently brittle and non-portable, due to limited line buffer sizes in various implementations. IIRC one does not need to worry much if using the GNU versions, but not everyone does that. Anyway, it seems to me that `sed` or `awk` are far better suited to this sort of task than non-standard extended `grep`s or `perl`: both seem too complex for a simple "`sed` 101" question like this, and extended `grep`s are probably equally non-portable.

Comment: @underscore_d this site is about Ubuntu, so portability isn't really an issue. And learning more about what `grep`, or any other tool, can do is always a good thing (even if just for fun) isn't it?

Comment: @Zanna I didn't even notice this was Ask Ubuntu... all of SE blurs together some days. :D But it's not unreasonable to suppose that enough people who happen to use Ubuntu might be interested in writing portable shell. And sure, don't get me wrong, I think this answer is useful by showing how this _could_ be done with some forms of `grep`, but just wanted to note some (if theoretical) limitations and alternatives.

Answer (score 4):

A solution `awk` could look like: `awk '/if/,/endif/' file`

Of course, it is similar to the solution with `sed`.

Comment: Yes, this works as well. One difference is between the `sed` and `awk` solution: If I replace `file` by `*` I get different results. `sed` seems to search only for ascii files(?) and `awk` includes binary files as well.